# Fast solving system of equations

Tags: algorithm

What is the fastest way to solve a system of equations 
for example

```
   3x+2y=10
    5x+6y=-2
```

using algorithms or fast code?

Comment: what would the fast code be implementing if not an algorithm? brute force?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a linear algebra problem and falls under [solutions of linear systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra#Solution_of_linear_systems).

The main article on wikipedia is here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

There are many ways of solving such systems and there are well studied, well-implemented solutions for almost every language. For example, in python you could use [`numpy.linalg.solve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html).

```
>>> a = np.array([[3,1], [1,2]])
>>> b = np.array([9,8])
>>> x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
>>> x
array([ 2.,  3.])
```